# jQuery this keyword conflict with typescript this

Tags: jquery, typescript

I a new hand of typescript
when I use jQuery,

```
export class IDE{
    init():any{
    $("select").on("change",function(){
        this.run();//cannot working because we in jQuery context.
    })

    }

    run():any{
    }
}
```

this keyword is override by jQuery 'this' keyword, could anyone give me some idea?

Comment: just change context from this into var that = this

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**You can solve the context issue , by 3 ways  , Here you go :**

> **1)** Use **[fat arrow](https://hackernoon.com/getting-to-grips-with-es6-arrow-functions-ebfa62c5c5d6)** :

```
$("select").on("change",() => {
    this.run();
})
```

---

> **2)** Use `bind` :

```
$("select").on("change",function(){
    this.run();
}.bind(this)); // <----- HERE
```

---

> **3)** Pass the reference of `this` :

```
export class IDE{

    init():any {
        let self = this;
        $("select").on("change",function(){
            self.run();
        })
    }

    run():any{
    }
}
```

> **Reason For Not Working Before :** every new function defined its own this value (based on how function was called, a new object in the case of a
>   constructor, undefined in strict mode function calls, the base object
>   if the function is called as an "object method", etc.)

Comment: Could you explain what you have said about "Reason For Not Working Before"? I didn't figure it out, give me some tips or urls is enough :)

Comment: @toffee . , please check the link in answer and https://hackernoon.com/javascript-es6-arrow-functions-and-lexical-this-f2a3e2a5e8c4 also this. it bit tricky to get it at first time.